# Is there any way do create a vm in azure without temporary storage drive?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I used this command to spin up a virtual machine :

```
az vm create -n $virtualMachine -g $resourceGroup --size Standard_D2_v3 --image win2016datacenter --data-disk-sizes-gb 40
--location $location --admin-username $admin --admin-password $password
```

Every time it creates a Drive D labeled "Temporary Storage", Is there any way I could get rid of this drive?

P.S I know what it dose and I do not need it.

Comment: Afaik this is mandatory for Azure VMs. So I think you will have to live with it. What's the problem?

Comment: I have an application that should be using drive D, and Drive d must me 1TB, so I can not use this Temporary Storage, due to the fact that the data might get wiped from it

Comment: Hmmm ... wow ...  you might contact the vendor of that application and ask to adapt the application to the 21st century.  ;-) :-D

Comment: believe me, you can not mess with them ...

Comment: Either with them or Microsoft ... not that many options  ...  your choice.  ;-) I'm sorry for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came up with this solution:

```
$resourceGroup = "your resource group name"
$virtualMachine = "your virtual machine name"

# remove page file from drive d
az vm run-command invoke -g $resourceGroup -n $virtualMachine --command-id RunPowerShellScript --scripts '$CurrentPageFile = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting"; $CurrentPageFile.delete(); Set-WMIInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="c:\pagefile.sys";InitialSize = 0; MaximumSize = 0}; Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom -Name Start -Value 4 -Type DWord'

# restart server
az vm restart -g $resourceGroup -n $virtualMachine

# set drive d and it's related disk into offline mode
az vm run-command invoke -g $resourceGroup -n $virtualMachine --command-id RunPowerShellScript --scripts 'get-disk -Number (Get-Partition -DriveLetter D).disknumber | Set-Disk -IsOffline $true'

# get azure disks and initialize, format and label it (assign a drive letter as well)
az vm run-command invoke -g $resourceGroup -n $virtualMachine --command-id RunPowerShellScript --scripts 'Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq "raw" | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "disk2" -Confirm:$false'
```

As @Charles Xu said you can not delete it but you can ignore it and make it offline.
it took me a wile to figure it out , yet it might save some time from others.

If you just need the powershell this is it:

```
$CurrentPageFile = Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting"; 
$CurrentPageFile.delete(); 
Set-WMIInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="c:\pagefile.sys";InitialSize = 0; MaximumSize = 0};
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom -Name Start -Value 4 -Type DWord
# you need to restart at this stage
get-disk -Number (Get-Partition -DriveLetter D).disknumber | Set-Disk -IsOffline $true
Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq "raw" | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "disk2" -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all the Azure virtual machines at least have two disks, one is operating system disk and another is the temporary disk. And the temporary disk comes with the VM size. You can see the [vm sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes), echo one with Temp storage.

So you cannot create a VM without the temporary disk. What you need to think is how to change your application with the need of drive number. For example, change the disk need as drive number E.

Comment: It seems you are right, but my question is how to get rid of it, is there away to remove the drive?

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi No, you cannot remove it. But if need, you can change the drive number after you create the VM.

Comment: I do agree that it is helpful, but unfortunately it is not the answer to the question and if I accept is as an answer it might misguide others, I have added the way I solved it.  Indeed you would get a vote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Dated 18-02-2021
Azure VM sizes with no local temporary disk, Now it's possible
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-vms-no-temp-disk